# How can I sort by column in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

how can I sort a text file by 3rd column in PowerShell?
That is part of the file:

```
    reza             zabihi          12     1
    maryam           joraee          17     2
    leyla            ahmadi          13     2
    farzin           farahbakhsh     16     1
    keyvan           maleki          8      1
    kaveh            ahangar         18     1
    nooshafarin      bakhtiari       13     2
    roya             afrashteh       13     2
    asghar           nazemi          18     1
    jaleh            nooruzi         16     2
    ali              samadi          6      1
    mohsen           adibi           3      1
    firooz           karimi          7      1
    mostafa          rostamian       18     1
    jafar            omidi           6      1
    shima            zagrosi         12     2
    somayyeh         modaberi        16     2
    shahram          zamani          16     1
    sayeh            rahmati         3      2
    shirin           rahjoo          12     2
```

I tried

```
Get-Content namef | Sort-Object { [double]$_.Split()[-2] } -Descending
```

Comment: why does this seem like an assignment?

Comment: anyhow, your best bet will be to sort by 3rd column using powershell and mail it using powershell. You however are not saying what the file type is.

Comment: I want to sort it by 3rd column. can u help?

Comment: read this
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/10/order-your-output-by-easily-sorting-objects-in-powershell/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one potential solution:

```
Get-Content yourfile.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Line = $_.Trim() -Split '\s+'

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        FirstName = $Line[0]
        LastName = $Line[1]
        FirstValue = [int]$Line[2]
        SecondValue = [int]$Line[3]
    }

} | Sort-Object FirstValue | Format-Table
```

This uses `Get-Content` to load your file, then uses a `ForEach-Object` loop to iterate through each line of that file (where the line is represented by the automatic variable `$_`).

It uses the `.Trim()` method on the line to remove the trailing whitespaces, then splits the line using the RegEx string `\s+` which represents one or more spaces.

After this `$Line` is now an array with each element excluding the spaces, so we create a custom PowerShell object where we give each item a name and access it's corresponding value from `$Line` via the Array index operator `[0]`..`[1]` etc. We cast the value columns as `[int]` so that they will be sorted later correctly (vs it treating them like strings).

Now that we've output a PowerShell object, we can simply pipe out result to `Sort-Object` with the FirstValue property and then send that to `Format-Table` to get a table result.

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there already. The reason why your code doesn't work the way you expect is that the `Split()` method splits the string at *each* space, so you're getting a lot of empty columns. What you actually want is to split at *consecutive* whitespace. To do the latter use the `-split` operator:

```
Get-Content namef | Sort-Object { [double]($_ -split '\s+')[-2] } -Descending
```

Answer (score 1):

So you already have 2 answers on how to get the result, I am adding one on how to send the email, which was part of your original requirement. You edited the question removing it, but I already did most of the answer, so I am posting it regardless.

Use powershell's `Send-MailMessage` which comes standard on a windows system by running it in a batchfile:

***NOTE!!** It must be powershell 2.0 or later.*

```
powershell Send-MailMessage 
           -From "someone@someserver.net"
           -To "whoever@gmail.com"
           -Subject "Test email"
           -Body "This is a test"
           -SmtpServer Some_exhange_server_name
```

I broke down the above text using newlines for readability, but it should be a single line as per below.

```
Send-MailMessage -From "someone@someserver.net" -To "whoever@gmail.com" -Subject "Test email" -Body "This is a test" -SmtpServer some_exhange_Server_name
```

All you have to do still is to replace the body text `This is a test` with the variables from the relevant solution you choose and from the other answers.